# Program design with multiple data sets, algorithms and results

Tags: java, design, data

I have a question regarding the design of my software.

The question has already been posted by me at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638697/program-design-with-multiple-data-sets-algorithms-and-results, but there I got the hint that this might be a better place to ask.

There are four different data sets and three consecutive algorithms operating on the data sets and on the results from the previous algorithm runs.

Let D1 - D4 be the set of data sets, A1 - A3 the set of algorithms and R1 - R3 the set of results from the respective algorithms.

A1 uses data sets D1, D2 and D3 and has to run on n different parameters. A2 uses data sets D1 and D3 as well as R1_1 - R1_n. A3 uses data sets D1, D2 and D4 as well as R2.

```
  D1    D1    D1
  D2    D3    D2
  D3          D4

  |     |     |
  v     v     v

n*A1    A2    A3
     _     _
  |  /| |  /| |
  v /   v /   v

R1_1    R2    R3
...
R1_n
```

Each of the results R1_1 - R1_n, R2 and R3 should have some output functionality.

So my question is how to organize the program and its classes. I guess I would want to create separate classes for each of D1 - D4, A1 - A3 and R1 - R3 and make the data and result objects attributes of the algorithm objects? Are there any reasons for or against creating n objects R1_1 - R1_n instead of one object R1 containing an array of n results?

Should the data classes include their own respective 'readFromFile' functions or would it be better to have a global utility class that reads all data from file and generates the data objects? The same goes for output functions, should they be placed in each of the result classes or should they be globally organized?

Kind regards!